# For loop in AWS step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have 20 AWS accounts and we create resources in 10 regions in each account. We want to ensure that AWS resources - ELB, AMI and EBS snapshots are properly tagged. We want to have a service that runs periodically to scan the accounts and delete any of the above mentioned resource that is not properly tagged. We want this to be serverless and we were looking at using Lambda. However, there are 2 issues with Lambda:

1. Lambda timeout - currently it is 5 mins.
2. Throttling errors

We need to ensure that we process the next account after the first account processing is completed (we could put a hard sleep for a few minutes and then start processing the next account).

Has someone faced a similar scenario and if so, how was it achieved?

Worst case scenario: we will use ECS.

Answer (score 0):

First, can your innermost task complete in under 5 minutes reliably? If so Lambda is a good fit. Your situation looks to be a good fit.

Next, throttling is easily raised by requesting a higher limit through a support ticket.

Finally, try breaking this up into several smaller functions. Maybe something like this:

- delete-resource -- Deletes a single untagged resource
- get-untagged-resources -- gets untagged resources in an account and invokes "delete-resource" in an async.each loop
- get-accounts -- gets list of accounts and invokes "get-untagged-resources" in an async.each loop

I actually prefer having my functions triggered by SNS rather than invoking them directly, but you get the idea. Hope this helps.

Comment: While I prefer this approach and have implemented it, when we have a lot of accounts, we need to wait for a few seconds between each one. The reason is that: for each region in every account, we need at least 2 describe calls (per service). The second and third Lambda functions will have very few API calls.

The throttling error occurs in the first part and that's where I wanted to use STEP functions so that between each account, we can add a wait / sleep condition.